# Android: Add programmatically multiple views to linear layout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout, android-view, dynamically-generated

I'm not sure how to handle that. I need linear layout which needs to have 20+ TextView and EditText components. I can define ImageView and buttons on top but I don't know how to generate rest of the components below and then put a button at the end.

It will look something like this:

```
---Button-----Button-------

--------ImageView----------

TextView -------- EditText

Item1.............[-------]

Item2.............[-------]

Item3.............[-------]

Item4.............[-------]

.

.

.

------------Button------------
```

There will be really a lot of components so I would like to avoid defining all components by hand in XML. After clicking on button all components need to be saved in pairs "name":"value" ("Item1":"EditText value"). I have a list of item's names and user will write the values for those items and save them to JSON file.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should use a ListView with a customized Adapter

Comment: Thank you. This is good idea but I have a little problem with my layout. Those buttons, field for text input and image occupy a lot of space so I needed to put all that inside `ScrollView`. The problem is that now I can't put `ListView` inside that `ScrollView`. Warning in XML: `The vertically scrolling ScrollView should not contain another vertically scrolling widget (ListView)`

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement a class like this.

```
public class DetailedTicketSystemView extends LinearLayout 
{
    static int inc = 100;
    ArrayList<XmlScommessaInCorso> _viewData;
    ArrayList<xmlSistemaMovimenti> _systems;
    Context _context;

    public DetailedTicketSystemView(Context context, int res, AttributeSet attrs, ArrayList<XmlScommessaInCorso> viewData, ArrayList<xmlSistemaMovimenti> systems) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        _context = context;
        _viewData = viewData;
        _systems = systems;

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(res, this, true);
        setId(inc);
        inc++;

        setLayout();
    }

    private void setLayout()
    {
        TextView textView;
        String text;

        for (int i = 0; i < _systems.size(); i++)
        {       
            View quotesView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(R.layout.row_ticket_detail_system_layout, null, true);
            quotesView.setId(i);

            // System Id
            textView = (TextView) quotesView.findViewById(R.id.systemId);
            text = "" + _context.getString(R.string.id_sistema) + " " + _systems.get(i).getAttributeOrVoidString(xmlSistemaMovimenti.ATTR_id) +
                    " / " + _viewData.size();
            textView.setText(text);

            // System Columns
            textView = (TextView) quotesView.findViewById(R.id.systemColumns);
            text = "" + _context.getString(R.string.colonne) + " " + _systems.get(i).getAttributeOrVoidString(xmlSistemaMovimenti.ATTR_n_multiple_sis);
            textView.setText(text);

            // System Bet Text
            textView = (TextView) quotesView.findViewById(R.id.systemBetText);
            textView.setText(R.string.importoPerColonna);

            // System bet Value
            textView = (TextView) quotesView.findViewById(R.id.systemBetValue);
            text = "€ " + XmlScommessaInCorso.getQuotaFormattedOrVoid(_systems.get(i).getAttributeOrVoidString(xmlSistemaMovimenti.ATTR_impo_sistema));
            textView.setText(text);


            LinearLayout primaryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.primaryLayout);
            primaryLayout.addView(quotesView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you need only a custom class or a listview.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it if I don't succeed with ListView.